# svn "Connection reset by peer" error during commit .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, svn

I can't commit .htaccess files only. When I am try to commit on terminal , I am getting this error:

```
svn: PUT of '/svn_sr/!svn/wrk/2ce2c337-a371-411d-ae18-c39acaa2d846/trunk/crm/.htaccess': Could not read status line: Connection reset by peer (http://www.xxx.com)
```

I am getting below error when I try to commit on zend-studio:

```
svn: Connection reset
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn_sr/trunk/crm/.htaccess'
```

I think this is permission problem.But I don't know how can I solve. I was find a few stuff about this problem on the web but I can't understand or I can't solve problem.

My virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.xxx.com
        DocumentRoot /home/umutftp
        <Location /svn_sr>
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /var/svn/sr
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Development area"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

        <Directory /home/umutftp>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx_error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I know little English. I will be happy if you are explain in simple language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a section that looks like this...

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

...or anything similar, elsewhere in your configuration?

This is in Apache's default configuration pretty much no matter where you got it.  It's specifically built to break access to `.htaccess` files; remove it to be able to work with them in SVN.

Comment: Yes,I have.I inactive this section but the problem not solved.Also I tried inactivate rewrite engine in .htaccess file  at main directory(/home/umutftp) but this also did not work :(

Comment: What does the Apache access log record when that request is attempted?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wJzDHS34

Comment: I don't see the `PUT` request or any attempt at it in that log, just the propfind that failed in the expected way.  See if you can find that request in the log?  Also, try setting `AllowOverride None` in the `<Location /svr_sr>` block.

Comment: When I commit other file I see the PUT request in access log file but when I try to commit .htaccess file I don't see PUT request.Also AllowOverride rule not change anything.

Comment: Strange.. any chance you can capture the attempt with a packet capture tool like Wireshark?  The connection reset is especially odd; does this Apache server run anything IPS-like, such as mod_security?  Or is there an IPS, web application firewall, or other firewall that sticks its nose in HTTP in front of it?

Comment: Thanks you @ShaneMadden.The reason of this is firewall probably because I am trying from home now and I can commit without any error. :)

Comment: Nice!  I'm not too surprised - a request for `PUT /somewhere/.htaccess` seems likely to trip some hardcoded IPS rules.  Consider running your SVN traffic over HTTPS to avoid that issue.